# Got java "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0" when installing Hadoop on AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, hadoop

I am following these videos to install Hadoop on AWS EC2:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cr5RmnyWbYw

But got this poblem with very end steps:

$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-dfs.sh

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/SequenceFileAsBinaryOutputFormat : U                                                                                               nsupported major.minor version 52.0

I did some search and was told this is because the java version not match. I tried to install java-sdk-8 but not help.

The ubuntu system I used is 14.04, and this is the java version information:
~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.11) (7u151-2.6.11-0ubuntu1.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.151-b01, mixed mode)

Any suggestion will be appreciated~~

Comment: You're correct - version 52 is a Java8 compiled class.  You'll need to get Java8 working on the machine.  Follow [these instruction](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464755/how-to-install-openjdk-8-on-14-04-lts) for a bit more information about installing Java8.

Comment: Use an older version of Hadoop or a newer version of Java

Comment: Thanks, it works now~

Comment: how did you solve?